# Laravel Routes Url issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello Everyone I am posting this question because I don't find this anywhere so please try to provide solution for this problem.

```php
Route::get('/product/{Cat_Slug}/{slug}','ProductController@SingleProductShow')>name('SingleProduct.Show');
```

This is my route and i want to remove 'product' from url and make my url like. [www.example.com/productCat_Slug/ProductSubCat_Slug](http://www.example.com/productCat_Slug/ProductSubCat_Slug) and want to access all related products but when i do this other routes effected.

Comment: What do you mean by other routes affected?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your other routes (those affected by your changes) come *before* this route in `routes/web.php`, so they are "hit" first.

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
Route::get('/{user}', 'TestController@user');
```

instead of

```
Route::get('/{user}', 'TestController@user');
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
Route::get('/{Cat_Slug}/{Subcat_slug}','ProductController@SingleProductShow')->name('SingleProduct.Show');
```

After that you will be able to access the values contained in Cat_Slug and Catsub_slug in your controller and make the query you want.

You also have a syntax error close to the route name. use `->name('myRouteName')` instead of `>name('myRouteName')`